# Oracle database and time zones

Tags: oracle, timezone

I'm working with an oracle database.
Every table got a creationdate and lastmodified field.
lastmodified is the actual time of the time zone ( UTC+1 + summer time if needed), while creationdate is the same time, but at UTC+0, leaving a difference of 2 hours in summer time and 1 hour otherwise.
Is there a way to change the creationdate so it's also using utc+1 + summer time when needed ? Thanks

Comment: What are the data type of these columns and how they are filled?

Comment: it's type Date, and I don't know how they're filled, but each time I send a request, when I create a new line, the field creationdate is updated, and when it's just an update, lastmodified is updated, it's automatic, maybe it's done by oracle, or maybe it's configurated somewhere else, don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Zurich';
SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TO_CHAR(creationdate,'yyyymmddhh24miss"UTC"'), 'yyyymmddhh24missTZR') AT LOCAL AS creationdate_local_TIMESTAMP,
    CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TO_CHAR(creationdate,'yyyymmddhh24miss"UTC"'), 'yyyymmddhh24missTZR') AT LOCAL AS DATE) AS creationdate_local_DATE  
FROM your_table;
```

You must set you session time zone to region like above. If you use static value (e.g. `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '+02:00';`) it will not work properly.

Important note: if you update your table with converted time values, then you must ensure that you don't do it several times, because every update your time would be shifted by 1 or 2 hours again and again.

Comment: I tried it, and as a result I had 2 fields : creation_local_timestamp and creation_local_date. Both with the time I'd like to have, but when I looked at the values of my creationdate field, it was still the same, like if nothing happened. I'm looking for a solution that would update the already existing creationdates but also that for each new rows, the creationdate will match this timezone too, like lastmodified already did